# ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user (using password: YES)

Tags: mysql, database-connection

I am trying to have a simple mysql Database on a server and another database on another server that connects to it.

I have done the following :

1. Installed mysql-server
2. Created the database
3. Created the user with :

   CREATE USER admin@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'admin';
4. Given the privileges to this user with :

   GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON confWeb.* TO admin@'';
5. Opened the bind-adress

Now when I launch the command `mysql -u admin -p -h <address>` from another server, it just tells me again and again :

```
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'admin'@'X.X.X.X' (using password: YES)
```

I really have no idea what to do at this point. I think I've tried everything. 
I tried putting `GRANT OPTION` in the end of the GRANT line, I tried allowing a lot of different addresses but nothing worked.

Comment: You created a user tied to localhost, but you're connecting to a server that's not localhost.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In MySQL, a user is identified by both *user* and *host*.

This user:

```
 admin@localhost
```

is *not* the same user as

```
 admin@'10.242.167.235'
```

---

As one option, you could do this to allow connection:

```
  GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO admin@'10.242.167.235' IDENTIFIED BY 'mysecret' ;
  GRANT ALL ON confWeb.* TO admin@'10.242.167.235' ;
```

For a longer discussion of the MySQL Access Privilege System, including "wildcards", the special meaning of localhost, using IP addresses instead of hostnames, etc.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privilege-system.html

Comment: I think your answer might be good for what I wrote, but I tried doing what you said and it still didn't work.
But I have found the solution, I'll post it.

Comment: And it's not the same as just `admin` apparently: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/191606/error-1045-28000-access-denied-for-user-myuserlocalhost-using-password

Comment: @pyb: correct.  a MySQL account is identified by both *user* and *host*.   According to the MySQL Reference Manual:  "The *host* name part of the account name, if omitted, defaults to `'%'`." https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-user.html   So specifying "just `admin` " is the same as specifying `admin@'%'`.

Answer (score 2):

I do not really know why, but appareantly, it worked when I used the `with grant option` and first gave access to the database, and then to its tables. 
Here is the list of commands that I entered :

```
mysql> create user 'admin'@'localhost' identified by 'admin';
mysql> grant all privileges on confWeb to 'admin'@'10.69.101.%' identified by 'admin' with grant option;
mysql> grant all privileges on confWeb.* to 'admin'@'10.69.101.%' identified by 'admin' with grant option;
mysql> flush privileges;
```

Again, I don't really know why it didn't work before and the answers that I saw look like all the documentation I have seen but it looks my problem was somewhere else.

Comment: `'admin'@'localhost'` is an entirely *different* user than `'admin'@'10.69.101.%'`. And neither of those users will be a "match" for a connection from `10.242.167.235`. If a connection is established from `10.242.167.235`, then *neither* of the two users defined by the statements shown in this answer make any difference.  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/account-names.html

Answer (score 0):

Use following step:-

```
  CREATE USER 'user name'@'IP or % or localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';

  GRANT all privileges ON *.* TO 'user name'@'IP or % or localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password' ;
  flush privileges;
```

Here in the place of "IP"; you use remote server ip where you want to connect the server.You can also use "%" for useage databases from any plcae in the world.

Now, in Grant option; In the place of "all privileges" you can given access seperately like as select,alter,update etc.